# Token "=" is not valid in preprocessor expressions

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I have a program:

```
#include <iostream>

#define _DEBUG = 1

using namespace std;
int main() {
        #if (_DEBUG == 1)
                cout << "hello : " <<endl;
        #endif

        return 0;
}
```

Compiling this gives the error:

```
$ g++ a.cpp
a.cpp:7:7: error: token "=" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
$ g++ --version
g++ (MacPorts gcc46 4.6.3_8) 4.6.3
```

I thought `==` is the equality conditional operator?

Comment: Don't use names starting with an underscore and either another underscore or a capital letter; they are reserved for the implementation to do with as they wish.  It means that your use of `_DEBUG` could collide with something in the system headers, and it would be your code that is at fault.  Actually, you're generally best off not creating names that start with an underscore at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - bit of a nit: the reserved identifiers are names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter and names that **contain** two consecutive underscores. So, for example, `A__B` is reserved, as well as `__AB`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: you're correct that names containing double underscore are also reserved in C++.  I tend to think of that as a separate rule from 'do not start identifiers with underscore', not least because C does not have the double-underscore restriction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a typo, I think:

```
#define _DEBUG = 1
```

should be

```
#define _DEBUG 1
```

I do that all the time!

Comment: To anyone [cleaning up typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342), this instance looks to me to be an error that's common enough and consistent in the error message produced as to warrant keeping.

Answer (score 8):

```
#define _DEBUG = 1
```

This declares `_DEBUG` as a macro that expands to `= 1`, so when it is expanded in your conditional expression, you get

```
#if (= 1 == 1)
```

which is clearly not a valid conditional expression.  You need to remove the `=` from the macro definition:

```
#define _DEBUG 1
```

In addition, for "flag" macros like this, it is usually a good idea to test whether the macro is defined, not what the value of the macro is.  For example,

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
#define textToBeReplaced ReplacementText
```

The compiler will go through all of your code and replace all instances of textToBeReplaced with replacementText.

In your case it would be

```
#define _debug 1
```

On another note your

```
    #if(_debug==1)
```

<s>should</s>  could be

```
    #ifdef _debug
```

Notice how the 1 never comes into play here? this means you can actually just do

```
    #define _debug
```

and not set it to anything

Comment: 'Should' is a bit strong; 'could' would be correct.  They may have uses for `#define _DEBUG 2`, in which case the test for `_DEBUG == 1` could be correct.

Comment: good point,  that would definately be useful for multiple levels of debug and what not